# Offline management Syncup in android

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am working on SmartSync for Android for Lead Object. I am able to sync down but nothing gets synced up. I am not seeing any errors, not sure what the issue is. Has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I am facing the same issue but now I am able to manage it.
Earlier I have custom object Named Offline Order which has few Lookup fields at that time my synch up is not working. Then, I have changed all lookup fields into Text fields then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ive experienced the same issue , You should include the Id field while performing the syncup operation, or else it will just show that the syncup is completed , and it will work fine with the lookup fields , you dont have to change it to text fields.